# Evaluating cameras for cycling

Tags: bicycling

What are the pros and cons that I should consider when evaluating Cam One vs GoPro for cycling? They are both around the same price. I am just looking for a *decent* result. I like the LCD on the Cam One.

I haven't had experience using either. I am just looking for a durable, decent camera to take on cycling trips to make footage that I can edit on Final Cut Pro.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be the GoPro. I have the Hero HD and purchased the LCD screen... And never needed it. They operate with a fairly wide angle even at 1080 so simple aiming will negate the need for an LCD. Also, during its primary intended use, you aren't using the LCD screen so you should think of it like a conventional camera where an LCD is crucial. The lack of LCD also saves battery time immensely and the thing is unbelievably light.

With cycling you're going to enjoy the flexibility of all the GoPro attachments (helmet, bars, chest). Chest attachment is the popular choice among sports users as it provides the most stability. Unrelated, but I can also tell you that the suction cup is superb underwater :-)

Answer (score 1):

Everyone I know that does extremes sports uses the GoPro HD, They are light, tiny and durable.

I have seen my friends test it in the following situations:

- Scuba-diving
- Desert Motorbike Racing
- Downhill Cycling
- Sports Fishing (over and under water!)
- Downhill long-boarding
- Bungie jumping
- etc..

All of the cameras still standing.

Comment: In the same week I had it suction cupped to my wakeboard and dune buggying with rail attachment. It's a champ.